# How to delay error messages when an Angular form becomes invalid, but remove them as soon as it becomes valid?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, validation, rxjs

There are two fields in my Angular 9 Reactive form that must be either both filled or both empty. I'd like to delay error messages when the user is filling one of the fields while the other's empty. Eventually, I'd show an error. There's a function outputting either  error messages or an empty array, to be  displayed in the html template. I'm using RxJs `debounceTime` operator to delay the error message.

**Problem:** The messages stay on after the user completes the second field. How could I hide them as soon as the form becomes valid?

**Example code**

```js
  const form = formBuilder.group({
      //other controls with validation
      treatmentCount: undefined,
      controlCount: undefined,
    },{
      validators: this.validatorFunction() // either both controls must be filled or none
    } )

  function errors(treatment: number | undefined, control: number | undefined  ): string[]  {
     ...
  return isValid?[]:['Oops! Error'] }

  const errorMessages$: Observable<string[]> =  form.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(2000),
  map( value => {return errors(value.treatmentCount, value.controlCounnt)},
  )) // this is displayed in the html template
```

I tried to `merge` the `errorMessages$` with a "no errors" observable only firing `[ ]` immediately once the form's valid. However, this actually killed the delay in showing  errors. Trying `updateOn` blur didn't solve the  issue and had a worse UX.

PS. I've trawled the internet and SO for an answer, but sadly not much  for my specific question.

Comment: Could you share this example in a stackblitz? It'll be easier to fork and then replicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to check the error before your debounce time then use a debounce time conditonaly.

something like this :

```js
const errorMessages$: Observable<string[]> =  form.valueChanges.pipe(
  map(value => errors(value.treatmentCount, value.controlCounnt)),
  debounce(error => error ? timer(2000) : EMPTY)
) // this is displayed in the html template
```

Comment: is there not built in way to do this with angular? It is really annoying to add this to every FromControl element